# Cosine similarity using Armadillo C++ gives me negative results

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, armadillo

I have implmented a cosine similarity function which uses armadillo c++ linear library. My code is the next one:

```
double cosine_similarity(rowvec A, rowvec B)
{
   double dot = as_scalar(A*B.t());
   double denomA = as_scalar(A*A.t());
   double denomB = as_scalar(B*B.t());
   return dot / (sqrt(denomA) * sqrt(denomB)) ;
}
```

I have this matrix as an example:

-0.0261  -0.6780  -0.7338   0.0345

-0.0230   0.0082  -0.0400  -0.7056

-0.2590  -0.7052   0.6590  -0.0371

-0.9650   0.2072  -0.1551   0.0426

-0.0230   0.0082  -0.0400  -0.7056

When I calculate the cosine similarity between the second row vs all the rows i get the following results:

Similarity [1,0]: -1.07944e-16

Similarity [1,1]: 1

Similarity [1,2]: -1.96262e-17

Similarity [1,3]: -1.71729e-16

Similarity [1,4]: 1

Is this correct? Am worrying about the negative results even when what they mean is zero. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. cosine_similarity is used in this way:

```
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < redV.n_rows ; row++)
{
    double ans = cosine_similarity(redV.row(indicate), redV.row(row));
    cout << "Similarity [" << indicate << "," << row << "]: " << ans << endl;
    cout << "Similarity [" << indicate << "," << row << "]: " << norm_dot(redV.row(indicate), redV.row(row)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: why not just use the [norm_dot()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#dot) function instead?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I get the same results thought. When sm doing the same computations on matlab i get slightly different numbers..

Comment: You haven't shown your entire code. What is the code for calculating `Similarity [1,0]` ?  Show a specific example of how `cosine_similarity()`is used.

Comment: @hbrerkere I have edited the question so you should be able to see how I call the cosine similarity function.

Comment: Your code is still not complete - you haven't shown how `redV` is initialized. I get the following results: `Similarity [1,0]: 6.99982e-05`, `Similarity [1,1]: 1`, `Similarity [1,2]: -1.1143e-05`... These results are the same as Matlab and Octave. Maybe there is a problem with incorrect data in `redV`.

Comment: It'd also be helpful to see more decimal places to compare with Python/Octave/etc. But in general, the negative numbers you show are well within machine precision on doubles (see [epsilon](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)) and so the sign is not particularly meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems right, you’re just encountering machine precision issues. `A*B.t()` for `A` the third row and `B` for the second row (or vice versa) should be zero but isn’t, but is within machine precision. [Scipy’s `cosine`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine) has the same problem:

```
In [10]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

In [11]: 1 - cosine([-0.2590, -0.7052, 0.6590, -0.0371], [-0.0230, 0.0082, -0.0400, -0.7056])
Out[11]: -1.114299639159988e-05  # <=============== should not be negative!
```

(I subtract by 1 just because of how Scipy defines `cosine`. And this answer doesn’t match yours because you posted only four decimal points—but the punchline is, it’s negative.)

If you want to check whether a floating point number `x` is within machine precision of another `y`, compare their difference with `std::numeric_limits::epsilon`. See the definition of [`almost_equal` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon). You might want `cosine_similarity` to check if the result is `almost_equal` to 0 or 1, in which case return 0 or 1.